# Delete fields of certain type with generics-sop

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm currently evaluating `Generics.SOP` for a use case involving derivation of new, related data types from a given data type definition.

I want to start out by defining a "de Bruijinized" version of a data type representing lambda terms:

```hs
-- The reproducer needs only some of the LANGUAGE pragmas and imports,
-- but it might be convenient for your (or my) solutions
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module SOP where

import Data.SOP.NS
import Generics.SOP
import Generics.SOP.TH
import Data.Kind

newtype Var = V String
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype BindingOcc = B Var
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Expr
  = Var Var
  | App Expr Expr
  | Lam BindingOcc Expr

deriveGeneric ''Expr -- Code Expr = '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[BindingOcc, Expr]]
```

To derive the de Bruijinized version of `Expr`, I have to delete all `BindingOcc`s (and afterwards add a new `'[Int]` alternative, but one step after another). *How do I do that?* Perhaps with a function

```hs
-- Let's be absolutely explicit about it and inline `Code`
-- Also don't want to confuse the type-checker with a type
-- family that removes the field just yet
deleteBindingOcc_SOP :: SOP I '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[BindingOcc, Expr]]
                     -> SOP I '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[Expr]]
deleteBindingOcc_SOP arg = SOP $ trans_NS Proxy {- will be filled in below -} deleteBindingOcc_NP (unSOP arg)

deleteBindingOcc_NP :: NP I xs -> NP I (WithoutBindingOccs xs)
deleteBindingOcc_NP Nil = Nil
deleteBindingOcc_NP (x :* xs)
  | B _ <- x  = deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
  | otherwise = x :* deleteBindingOcc_NP xs

-- I guess I expected to write the following type family
type family WithoutBindingOcc (xs :: [Type]) :: [Type] where
  WithoutBindingOcc '[]                = '[]
  WithoutBindingOcc (BindingOcc ': xs) = WithoutBindingOcc xs
  WithoutBindingOcc (x          ': xs) = x ': WithoutBindingOcc xs
```

But alas, that doesn't type-check; for one, I match on the parametrically-polymorphic head of `xs` at runtime in the definition of `deleteBindingOcc_NP`, so I need a singleton encoding/derive a type class just for the purpose of defining my little helper function `deleteBindingOcc_NP`.

Here it is:

```hs
-- Now we know the full type of the proxy, carrying the constraint that `deleteBindingOcc_NP` wants
deleteBindingOcc_SOP arg = SOP $ trans_NS (Proxy :: Proxy MyC) deleteBindingOcc_NP (unSOP arg)

class b ~ WithoutBindingOcc a => MyC a b where -- welp
  deleteBindingOcc_NP :: NP I a -> NP I b
instance MyC '[] '[] where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP Nil = Nil
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} MyC a b => MyC (BindingOcc ': a) b where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP (_ :* xs) = deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} MyC a b => MyC (x ': a) (x ': b) where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP (x :* xs) = x :* deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
```

But even that doesn't work, because the overlapped instance won't type-check:

```
    • Could not deduce: WithoutBindingOcc (x : a) ~ (x : b)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: MyC a b
        bound by the instance declaration at SOP2.hs:52:31-62
    • In the instance declaration for ‘MyC (x : a) (x : b)’
   |
52 | instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} MyC a b => MyC (x ': a) (x ': b) where
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And upon thinking about it a bit, that is not surprising: There is no *guarantee* that the latter type class is never instantiated with a `BindingOcc` at its head `x`, which our type family should remove. So it appears that a type class based approach is not what I want here.

My question is: How do write `deleteBindingOcc_SOP` with the given type signature in a manner that it works with different, but similarly related `Code`s?

I fear that the `Code` representation as a list of list of *meta-language* `Type` constructs may not be suitable to achieve what I want. Somehow we can't know that all the `Type`s are in fact closed and won't be substituted any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a type family to relate the original and stripped types, perhaps we could rely on a functional dependency:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-} -- required by some of the magic below
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

class MyC a b | a -> b where 
  deleteBindingOcc_NP :: NP I a -> NP I b
instance MyC '[] '[] where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP Nil = Nil
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} MyC a b => MyC (BindingOcc ': a) b where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP (_ :* xs) = deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} MyC a b => MyC (x ': a) (x ': b) where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP (x :* xs) = x :* deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
```

This seems to work:

```
deleteBindingOcc_SOP :: SOP I '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[BindingOcc, Expr]]
                     -> SOP I '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[Expr]]
deleteBindingOcc_SOP arg = SOP $ trans_NS (Proxy @MyC) deleteBindingOcc_NP (unSOP arg)
```

An alternative version with an auxiliary `MyC'` class instead of overlapping instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Equality

class MyC a b | a -> b where 
  deleteBindingOcc_NP :: NP I a -> NP I b
class MyC' (isocc :: Bool)  a b | a -> b where 
  deleteBindingOcc_NP' :: NP I a -> NP I b
instance MyC '[] '[] where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP Nil = Nil
instance MyC' (x == BindingOcc) (x ': xs) ys => MyC (x ': xs) ys where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP = deleteBindingOcc_NP' @(x == BindingOcc)
instance MyC a b => MyC' True (BindingOcc ': a) b where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP' (_ :* xs) = deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
instance MyC a b => MyC' False (x ': a) (x ': b) where
  deleteBindingOcc_NP' (x :* xs) = x :* deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea whether what you're doing is a good idea ...

But all that aside, here is something that works for at least your simple use case.

```hs
type family Equal (a :: k) (b :: k) :: Bool where
  Equal a a = True
  Equal _ _ = False

type family IfThenElse (b :: Bool) (t :: a) (e :: a) where
  IfThenElse True  t _ = t
  IfThenElse False _ e = e

class CanDecide (b :: Bool) where
  ifthenelse :: Proxy b -> ((b ~ True) => r) -> ((b ~ False) => r) -> r

instance CanDecide True  where ifthenelse _ x _ = x
instance CanDecide False where ifthenelse _ _ y = y

class    CanDecide (Equal a BindingOcc) => IsBindingOcc a
instance CanDecide (Equal a BindingOcc) => IsBindingOcc a

type family DeleteBindingOcc (xs :: [Type]) :: [Type] where
  DeleteBindingOcc '[]      = '[]
  DeleteBindingOcc (x : xs) = IfThenElse (Equal x BindingOcc) (DeleteBindingOcc xs) (x : DeleteBindingOcc xs)

class    (All IsBindingOcc xs, DeleteBindingOcc xs ~ ys) => RelDeleteBindingOcc xs ys
instance (All IsBindingOcc xs, DeleteBindingOcc xs ~ ys) => RelDeleteBindingOcc xs ys

deleteBindingOcc_NP :: RelDeleteBindingOcc xs ys => NP f xs -> NP f ys
deleteBindingOcc_NP Nil = Nil
deleteBindingOcc_NP ((x :: f x) :* xs) =
  let
    ys = deleteBindingOcc_NP xs
  in
    ifthenelse (Proxy @(Equal x BindingOcc)) ys (x :* ys)

deleteBindingOcc_SOP :: SOP I '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[BindingOcc, Expr]]
                     -> SOP I '[ '[Var], '[Expr, Expr], '[Expr]]
deleteBindingOcc_SOP arg = SOP $ trans_NS (Proxy @RelDeleteBindingOcc) deleteBindingOcc_NP (unSOP arg)
```

BTW, there is a nice-looking library called [generic-data-surgery](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-surgery) (that I unfortunately never used myself) that claims to be good at this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think this will be entirely too painful. I was hoping to find a neat TH-based library that does the job but couldn't find one. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to polytypically encode this "de Bruijinisation" of a term data type. I had hoped to build on and extend Generalizing Generlized Tries, where I want to de Bruijnize terms on the fly before inserting or looking them up in the de Bruijnized trie. Seems I just stick to code examples demonstrating the pattern, then